# I am tring to create a digraph to represent a DFA (deterministic finite automata)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to LaTeX, so the more details the better. Thanks!
[image: DFA]

Comment: Just have a look at the automata library of TikZ which is the way to go.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Here on site are plenty of solution for similar automaton. Also in *TikZ & PGF* documentation you can find exaples of similar automaton.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the term "digraph" in the question.  I know this term to mean "two letters treated as a unit". as `\ae` or the Dutch "IJ".  The image in the question shows something entirely different.  Is this a common usage, or is there another term that might be used with less confusion?

Comment: @barbara A digraph in this context is a graph theoretic directed graph.  I guess it depends on ones mathematical neck of the woods, but this usage is quite common as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks.  So, probably shortened from "directed graph".  Learned something.  (My background is more heavily linguistics than mathematics.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525429/i-am-tring-to-create-a-digraph-to-represent-a-dfa-deterministic-finite-automata#comment1329051_525429) you can use the `automata` library here. You may want to use `foreach` loops to avoid repetition.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,positioning,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,>={Stealth[round]},
    every state/.style={draw},blue!60,text=black] 
 \path node[state,double] (S_0) {$S_0$}
   foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0,1}
  {node[state,right=of S_\X] (S_\Y) {$S_\Y$}};
 \path foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0,1}
  {(S_\X) edge[bend right,->,"\the\numexpr1-\X"'] (S_\Y)
   (S_\X) edge[bend left,<-,"\the\numexpr1-\X"] (S_\Y)}
  (S_2) edge [loop right,"1"] ()
  (S_0) edge [loop above,"0",rotate=45] ()
  (S_0) edge [<-] ++ (-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]